# How to call SQL Queries in ASP .NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to create login page using react front-end and ASP .NET core Back-end.
SO while a user login to the system I have to use the query like

> Select * from UserLogin where email="asbhf@gmail.com"

so that my API URL should be

> https://localhost:44383/api/UserLogins?email="asbhf@gmail.com"

So that, I tried this code in my UserLoginController.cs

```
// GET: api/UserLogins?email="asd@gmail.com"
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserLogin([FromRoute] string email)
        {
            if (email == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            string query = "SELECT * FROM UserLogin WHERE email = @email";
            var UserLogin = await _context.UserLogin
            .FromSql(query, email)
            .Include(d => d.Username)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (UserLogin == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(UserLogin);
        }
```

but, It won't print any out put as I expect. Could you please give me any hint to solve my issue.

Comment: ASP.NET Core already includes ASP.NET Identity for these jobs, and *already* stores users in a database in a secure manner. There's no reason to replace it with your own (most likely) insecure method

Comment: In fact, ASP.NET Core already contains a template with React.js in the front and ASP.NET Core in the back. [The template's documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) The latest version [supports SPA authentication out of the box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: As for the query, it will return the entire User row to the client, not just the user name. I'm pretty sure that's not the desired outcome, especially if that row contains sensitive data. If you want to retrieve the user name use `.Select()`, not `Include`. In *this* case though, where you use a raw SQL string, use `SELECT UserName From ....`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No sir. actully email address is a unique address. so that, I'm tring to get a details from that specific email addres. that means one user. this is for login system .

Comment: Why aren't you using the *built-in* login system? As for the query, assuming `UserLogin` contains **only profile information** ,  you need to *remove* `.Include()`. That's meant to include related entities, not specify the fields to return. All you need is `var user=await _context.UserLogin.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u=>u.Email=email);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refer [write sql query for entityframework](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx)

So my working code is

```
 var UserLogin = _context.UserLogin.Where(c => c.Email == email);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly , The `Include` method specifies the **related objects** to include in the query results. It can be used to retrieve some information from the database and also want to include **related entities** , not specify the fields to return. For more details , you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

Secondly , there are some errors in your data query section , try the following modification:

```
string query = $"SELECT Username FROM UserLogin WHERE email = @email";
var p1 = new SqlParameter("@email", email);

var UserLogin = await _context.UserLogin
              .FromSql(query, p1)
              .AsNoTracking()
              .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

You could take a look at [Executing Raw SQL Queries](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql) for the usage of `FromSql`.